# How to map xs:any in EMF Ecore?

Tags: xsd, eclipse-emf-ecore

I have the following type in an xsd:

```
<xs:complexType name="VendorSpecificType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any namespace="##any" processContents="skip" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

I created this type in Ecore:

[image: Ecore type]

I tried to inject an xml containing the following tags:

```
<VendorSpecific>
    <Vendor ID="1"/>
</VendorSpecific>
```

But it crashes

```
org.eclipse.m2m.atl.core.ATLCoreException: Error loading test.xml: org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi.FeatureNotFoundException: Feature 'Vendor' not found.
```

The code used to inject models in metamodels is tested and working. 
Even this test.xml is loaded correctly if I remove the Vendor tag.

My question is how to map the xsd any to an ecore type so it can be loaded?

UPDATE:

After debugging, it seems that the code I use to inject the model into the ecore model is not complete: the extendedmetadata is always null

```
// Load in metamodel
IReferenceModel metamodel = modelFactory.newReferenceModel();
injector.inject(metamodel, metamodelPath);

model = modelFactory.newModel(metamodel);
injector.inject(model, modelPath);
```

How do I tell it to load the metadata?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following line

```
((EMFModelFactory) modelFactory).getResourceSet().getLoadOptions().put(XMLResource.OPTION_EXTENDED_META_DATA, Boolean.TRUE);
```

before injecting the metamodel.

It works now!